# Query currently available venues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a collection of Venues and these venues has_many OpenTimes to tell if the venue is currently open on this time of the week. I want to query all of the venues that are currently open.

I currently have a method in `venue.rb` that is called 'def active' that goes through the open_times and checks if `Time.now` is in the range of the open_time's :start and :end fields.

How can I create a query that gives all of the currently open venues?

I'm hoping to create a scope that's something like `Venue.all.currently_available`

Comment: The Venue is open when it has at least one OpenTime with time ranges around Time.now, right?

Comment: Little ambiguous question: either you want to query all open Venues, or just check if venue is available. Pick one :)

Comment: Sorry, I clarified a little bit. I would like to query all available venues. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# in Venue class
def available?
  open_times.where(':now BETWEEN open_times.start AND open_times.end', now: Time.now).exists?
end
```

**UPD:** To query all open Venues use:

```
def self.currently_available
  joins(:open_times).
  where(':now BETWEEN open_times.start AND open_times.end', now: Time.now).
  uniq
end
```

Call: `Venue.currently_available`

Comment: it should be a lambda, I think. Otherwise Time.now will be evaluated only once, when the application is loaded.

Comment: right, I had a scope in mind :) for the "all the opened venues" as in the question. nm. :)